# Strange pushViewController behavior

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My app starts on `LoginViewController`.
The Login view has one button "Register", with the code shown below.
When app starts if I click on Register, nothing happens. But if I Login and Logout, then the Register Button works properly.

What should be the problem for this to happen?

AppDelegate:

```
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Load View Controllers;

    self.vcClubs = [[[ClubsViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.vcParties = [[[PartiesViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.vcEditProfile = [[[EditProfileViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    self.navClubs = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vcClubs] autorelease];
    self.navClubs.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    self.navParties = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vcParties] autorelease];
    self.navParties.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // Load Login View
    UIViewController *loginView = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginView;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
...
- (void)login
{
self.vcMenu = [[[MenuViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.vcLocationMenu = [[[LocationMenuViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.mainController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.mainController.leftViewController = self.vcMenu;
self.mainController.rightViewController = self.vcLocationMenu;

[self.mainController setMainViewController:self.navParties];
[self.mainController showMainViewControllerAnimated:YES];

self.window.rootViewController = self.mainController;

CATransition *transition = [[[CATransition alloc] init] autorelease];
transition.duration = 1;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[self.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"login"];
}
...
```

LoginController.php:

```
...
- (IBAction)onTapSignupButton:(id)sender
{
RegisterViewController *controller = [[[RegisterViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);
}
...
```

Return NSLOG on app Start:

```
2013-02-18 02:18:29.986 App[32652:c07] (null)
```

Comment: When you click Register, does the code above get executed (use breakpoint or NSLog to determine if the code is called). The code itself is fine.

Comment: @Joel Yeah it get executed but nothing happens.

Comment: Put an `NSLog()` for `controller` and `self.navigationController` and check whether none are nil.

Comment: For the sake of completness please post logout method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may look weird. but i done this same kind of mistake. Hope it helps you..

Check whether you have initialised UInavigationController in AppDelegate. If yes i dont know why you got this...If not try following code

```
RegisterViewController *controller = [[[RegisterViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller]
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

As per your edited code

```
 // Load Login View
UIViewController *loginView = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginView]
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: @LucianoNascimento In the Login view Controller you didn't add UINavigationController

Comment: @LucianoNascimento Check my new edit... If you are delivering your RegisterViewController from loginView ViewController no need of UINavigationController in my 1st part of code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the first time you try, LoginViewController is not being wrapped in navigation controller. I would check if login/logout cycle puts login controller inside navigation stack, and see why that is not happening the first time login is presented

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RegisterViewController *controller = [[[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: i think you forget to add nibName

Answer (score 0):

```
RegisterViewController *controller = [[[RegisterViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Your code is not right because of Objective C memory management
Firstly, you should check if your navigation controller is not nil.
And then^ the proper code will look like

```
RegisterViewController *controller = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```